# Visual Studio 2013: Find all implementations of an interface

Tags: visual-studio-2013, interface, implementation

Using `Visual Studio 2013` without `ReSharper`, is there any way to find which CLR types have implemented a certain interface for example `IDatabaseInitializer`?

Comment: Base VS has "Find References", right?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I want implementations in .net core assemblies not my solution

Comment: For stuff that's actually in .net core, you can use http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ - find the interface declaration, click the name. However, looks like IDatabaseInitializer is in EF, which is not core.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks it did help. Any way to inspect other Miscrosoft assemblies such as EntityFramework.dll ?

Comment: Yes, utiltiies like ILSpy or Reflector will let you examine the decompiled source of any .Net assembly.